# Adding more circles to SVG degrades performance drastically

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, opengl-es

I have a application where I draw a world map with D3 and I use latitude and longitude data from a different source to plot them on the map. Currently what I learnt from lot of google'ing is that i can plot points by appending "circle" to to the SVG, which works fine for first 15 to 20 seconds after my web page is opened, later everything gets too slow and sloppy.

I am not sure how to keep the performance of the page decent and not add a new DOM element for every single circle I append with SVG. Do I need to use some other technology to achieve this ? Please advice.

My code looks like below and I call this like 500 times every 5 seconds.

```
function draw_point(lat, lon, keyword) {
    var x = projection([lon, lat])[0];
    var y = projection([lon, lat])[1];
    svg.append("circle")
        .attr("cx", x)
        .attr("cy", y)
        .attr("r", 0.5)
        .style("fill", "gold");

        svg.append("text")
            .text(keyword)
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", y)
            .style("fill", "gold")
            .style("font-size", "10px")
            .transition()
            .duration(40)
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .remove();
}
```

To give a bit more context, I am trying to do something like this site http://tweetping.net/ In this page I see that new DOM element is not being added for every dot placed in the map, I am looking for something similar.

Answer (score 0):

The page which you mentioned uses canvas element and not svg or d3.js. You might want to look into

- [fabricjs](http://fabricjs.com/)
- [paperjs](http://paperjs.org/)
- [kinectjs](http://kineticjs.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Additional clarification of @VivekKumarBansal's suggestion: The general rule is that SVG slows down as more elements are added, but making images larger or smaller doesn't affect speed. Canvas doesn't slow down as more elements are added, but increasing size does slow it down. d3.js can be used with Canvas, although it seems to be more common to use it with SVG.